# Implementation hyperchaotic lorenz in matlab

Tags: matlab

I try this code for Implementation hyperchaotic lorenz in matlab:

```
    function Y=b(a,b,c,d,e,k)
      [T,Y]=ode45(@rigid,[0 e],[a b c d]);
    function out=rigid(t,y)
       out=zeros(4,1);
       out(1)=10*(y(2)-y(1));
       out(2)=28*y(1)+y(2)-y(1)*y(3)-y(4);
       out(3)=y(1)*y(2)-(8/3)*y(3);
       out(4)=0.1*y(2)*y(3)+k;
end;
end;
```

But when i call b function with value, i have this error:
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
could anyone help me with this code?

Comment: Try removing the semicolons after the `end` statements, particularly the last one. Also, FYI, one reason you probably got down-voted was because you provided a function with no way to run it, i.e., you didn't say what the inputs are.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you have a variable called `b` in your function named `b`?

Comment: @RobertP.: That doesn't seem to cause an issue (R2012b, OS X 10.8.4), but it certainly is not a good idea. It also may cause the code to be bit slower though as Matlab will need to figure out which `b` is being called.

Comment: @horchler: It works in R2013a as well. I tried running the code with some random integer inputs, and I did not get any errors. I suggest you follow horchler's advice and show your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your error is that you have a variable named `b` in the workspace.

The following works as a charm:

```
b(1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

The following does not:

```
a = 1; b = 1; c = 1; d = 1; e = 1; k = 1;

b(a,b,c,d,e,k)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

What do you get if you type

`whos b`?

Comment: Thank you and sorry for this obvious mistake(b).